# How can I output the \n?

Tags: java, file-io, io

**I tried to output this line below in a text file**

```
label= "Paul\n\n\D.Naiss:Inc"
```

**I tried like this:**

```
out.write("label= \"" +firstname+ " \"\n\n\"D.Naiss:Inc");
```

**but the \n does not appears. It writes**

label= "Paulo ""D.Naiss:Inc

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TEster {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello \\n World!");
    }
}
```

Will print..

```
Hello \n World!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a '\' on '\n' so that your code reads

```
out.write("label= \"" +firstname+ " \"\\n\\n\"D.Naiss:Inc");
```

Otherwise, it interprets a new line character itself should be placed in the text file.

The escape character before the \ character means that you want to actually print \ rather than a special character.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is a line feed special character, have you tried `\\n`?

`\\` will give a single \ character followed by the n.

If however you're after a line feed and the text editor isn't showing it correctly perhaps you're looking for a missing \r as well though?  e.g.

```
label= "Paul\r\n\r\n\D.Naiss:Inc"
```

Some windows editors look for \r\n but most will understand \n is all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output `\n` it won't be displayed because that's an escape sequence (inserts a new line).  Another example is if you want to output `\t`: write  `\\t`

Like the above comment you should write \n. Now Java won't identify this as an escape sequence but prints what you want